# Gnome-Do sometimes stops responding to superkey+spacebar

Tags: gnome-do

This seems to be on a random basis.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

(sorry for the lack of detail - it really does seem to be random)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it simply dies, and you need to restart it. Alternatively, the system could be temporally unresponsive and it might take more time that usual to invoke the launcher.

Comment: I don't think the system is busy so I guess it just dies. Is this normal? I have found most popular Linux apps/daemons to be very stable.

Comment: It's not normal for Ubuntu generally but gnome-do, bless its cotton socks, has had some bugs like this.  When it stops responding, find the pid in the system monitor or `ps`, and run `ubuntu-bug PID` to file a bug.